# Vue.js access parent/root data from a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My `main.js` file references `#app` as the `el`, and then on `ready` it sends an HTTP request to my API to get data on the user based on their token taken from `localStorage`.

It sets the data like so when the response is returned:

```
this.$http.get('/me', function(data) {
  this.$set('me', data.me);
})
```

After the above request returns a response, `data` now looks like this:

```
data = {
  me: {
    email: 'email@email.com',
    name: 'Email Email'
  }
}
```

And then in the `main.js` file I implement `vue-router` and my app is then bootstrapped.  It renders my side navigation and other components, and in the middle there is a `<router-view></router-view>` for the main content.

Ex (`app.html` rendered from `main.js`):

```
<div is="navigation"></div>
<router-view></router-view>
```

In my navigation component, and furthermore my components rendered by the `vue-router`, how can I access data that I want to be global, for example `me` which is set in the root component?

I want to be able to access data like the user's e-mail and name all over the app.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT:: Check out the new package Vuex - https://github.com/vuejs/vuex .  This is designed to be a high-level storage of app data that you can access from within any component.  This is definitely the best option now.

Original answer:

---

A few options that I can think of:

1) pass the current user data to each component that needs it.  This would be a bit annoying but maintains the principle that a component should not need any outside information to perform its function.

2) use `this.$parent` to move up the component chain to the root component, where you will be able to access the data you need.

3) just make a global variable.  Declare it outside the scope of Vue and have access to it wherever you want.

Comment: For option one, you're talking pass it as a `prop`?  For options two, I tried this, but `data` is undefined on `$parent`.  Could it be because it isn't set until the response from the HTTP request sets it?  Seems like option 2 would be the best which I've tried but logging it in the console is returning `undefined`.

Comment: Please see edit @Noah, there is a new package from the creator of Vue that is specifically meant for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`$root` works for me. At each level of components hierarchy, it refers to the root data.

For example you are inside a component and a sub component needs `email`, you  can do this to access the email:

`$root.me.email`