# Access the prop of the root component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

In my page, I have a set of components and subcomponents like that:

```
<TournamentTabs :tournament="{{ json_encode($tournament) }}">    
   <TournamentTab>
      <TournamentTabGeneral></TournamentTabGeneral>
      <TournamentTabVenue></TournamentTabVenue>
      etc.
   </TournamentTab>
</TournamentTabs>
```

Right now, I use Laravel for getting $tournament value.

Now, I would like prop tournament to be available to all TournamentTabs children, but when accessing `this.tournament`, I get `undefined`

How should I access `tournament` value in all chidlren???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js access parent/root data from a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122517/vue-js-access-parent-root-data-from-a-child-component)

Comment: Could you show the code for your components, are you trying to access that data from a slot?

Comment: I don t use slots. I will share the code when I can. I am in my car:)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it.

Firstly, the TournamentTabs is not a root component as I can see. Root component - it's the component where Vue instance mounts (in most cases `div#app`) that can be accessible via `this.$root` anywhere.

You can access it via `this.$parent.tournament`, but this is not a best way to do it, because you will end up like `this.$parent.$parent.$parent....tournament` if you need to access property from deeply nested components.

You can try vuex library to implement the central application storage.